# Zsh terminal can't run command

Tags: macos, zsh

I cannot run any command in my terminal. This is what is shown on the screen:

```
-zsh(8651,0x108442dc0) malloc: can't allocate region
:*** mach_vm_map(size=18446744072790204416, flags: 100) failed (error code=3)
-zsh(8651,0x108442dc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
/Users/phongvu/.zshrc:117: fatal error: out of memory

[Process completed]
```

Please help me!

Comment: What's on line 117 of your `.zshrc`?

Comment: @JordiNebot This is it:
```cat << EOF >> ~/.zshrc```

Comment: @agentp : Don't tell me that you are going to append to your .zshrc while the .zshrc iteslf is being processed?????

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
I installed VSCode in path with these lines:

```
cat << EOF >> ~/.zshrc
export PATH="\$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
EOF
```

and it installed path every time I use "code ." command which makes my zsh shell out of memory

Comment: Why do you need to append a line that already exists to `.zshrc`?